# Symfony2: how to override core template?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to override SymfonyGeneratorBundle templates by creating

```
\app\Resources\SensioGeneratorBundle\skeleton\crud\views\index.html.twig
```

That file should replace:

```
\vendor\bundles\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Resources\skeleton\crud\views\index.html.twig
```

But it still uses original file even after `cache:clear.` How to do that w/o creating new bundle like [Can't override the standard skeleton views in Symfony2 GeneratorBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227082/cant-override-the-standard-skeleton-views-in-symfony2-generatorbundle)?

Comment: shouldn't it be a "index.html.twig.twig" extension instead ? Note the double "twig".
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Register your bundle right after `SensioGeneratorBundle` in `app/AppKernel.php` e.g.:

```
// app/AppKernel.php

if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    //.....
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Namespace\YourBundle();
}

// Or outside if, should you want your bundle to be available in production environment
$bundles[] = new Namespace\YourBundle();
```

Then in `YourBundle.php`  override `registerCommands` method,

```
// Bundle\YourBundle.php

// other declarations
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\DoctrineCrudGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;


public function registerCommands(Application $application){
    $crudCommand = $application->get('generate:doctrine:crud');
    $generator = new DoctrineCrudGenerator(new FileSystem, __DIR__.'/Resources/skeleton/crud');
    $crudCommand->setGenerator($generator);

    parent::registerCommands($application);
}
```

You have to copy `skeleton` folder to `YourBundle\Resource` and modify templates.

Comment: I did exactly and get this error message:
  [Twig_Error_Loader]
  The "C:\wamp\apps\rerent\src\Rent\ProgramBundle/../Resources/skeleton/crud" directory does not exist.

I guess it tries to read from bundle instead from app/ folder. Help?

Comment: Forgot to tell you one caveat of this approach, you have to copy skeleton folder to your ProgramBundle. Also '../' is not required. Edited code.

Comment: YES. I copied skeleton to Bundle\MyBundle\Resources and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this will change in the latest version of the bundle: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/commit/573eed4d8f1b81b5dc8c1c2e52318c76f0709e9d
You'll be able to override the templates by placing them in app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton

Comment: I have the feeling you wanted to write `new FileSystem(__DIR__.'/Resources/skeleton/crud')` instead of `new FileSystem, __DIR__....`

Answer (score 12):

To override the edit template, for example, in 2.3+ version, copy the file:

```
vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Resources/skeleton/crud/views/edit.html.twig.twig
```

for the directory:

```
app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton/crud/views/edit.html.twig.twig
```

Now, just generate crud with the default command and it will use the new template.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of m2mdas worked for me, but only after discovering that it should read

Filesystem instead of FileSystem!

Take a look at your vendors/symfony/.../Filesystem folder to verify this.